# C union char array prints 'd' on mac?

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C/C++, but was curious to know about the issue i am seeing.

```
typedef union
{
   int a;
   float c;
   char b[20];
}
Union;

int main()
{
 Union y = {100};
 printf("Union y :%d - %s - %f \n",y.a,y.b,y.c);
}
```

And output is

```
 Union y :100 - d - 0.000000
```

My question is ...why is 'd' getting printed? I changed the order in union still the same output. but if i declare a char f[20] outside the union then nothing gets printed.
I am having MacBook lion image and using xcode.
THanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I changed the order in union still the same output.

The order of the elements in a union doesn't change anything because all the elements of a union use the same piece of memory. Your code prints `100` for `y.a` and `d` for `y.b` because both expressions interpret the same bytes. So, for example, if you add a line that sets `y.b` and then prints again:

```
Union y = {100};
printf("Union y :%d - %s - %f \n",y.a,y.b,y.c);
y.b = 'f';
printf("Union y :%d - %s - %f \n",y.a,y.b,y.c);
```

you'll see that `y.a` and `y.c.` change whenever `y.b` changes, and vice versa. `y.a` should change to 102 in the second `printf()`, since that's the ASCII character code for `'f'`.

Answer (score 10):

The ASCII code for `'d'` is 100. Setting `a` to 100 amounts to setting `b` to `{'d', '\0', '\0', '\0', …noise…}` (on a 32-bit little-endian machine), which `printf` treats as `"d"`.

Comment: And why does `c` get printed as `0.0000`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Because of the way [IEEE floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) are stored in memory.

Comment: Also, why do you have `\0, \0` and what is `noise`

Comment: @0x499602D2 The size of the union is the size of its longest element, 20 bytes in your example. Setting the integer sets the first 4 bytes (on a 32-bit machine), the other 16 (noise) are left uninitialized.

Comment: @Sulthan Wow thanks for clearing that up! I'm not too familiar with unions.

Answer (score 4):

The following program may help you understand better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
    int a;
    float c;
    char b[20];
}
Union;

void dump(const void* buffer, size_t length)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < length;) {
        printf("%.2x ", reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer)[i]);
        ++i;
        if (i % 16 == 0) {
            putchar('\n');
        } else if (i % 8 == 0) {
            putchar(' ');
        }
    }
    if (i % 16 != 0) {
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    Union y = {100};
    printf("Union y :%d - %s - %f \n",y.a,y.b,y.c);
    printf("The content of the Union is: \n");
    dump(&y, sizeof y);
}
```

The output is:

```
Union y :100 - d - 0.000000 
The content of the Union is: 
64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00
```

Effectively, the binary representation of *a* (which is a `int`) is `64 00 00 00`, 100 in little-endian hexadecimal. The binary representation of *b* is `64 00 ...`, and the 0x00 ends the string, while 0x64 is 'd'. The binary representation of *c* is `64 00 00 00`, which in the [IEEE float representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) is 0.0, because the non-zero part is the exponent.

Comment: +1 for the helpful example. However, `c` isn't 0.0, it's 1.401298464324817e-43 (a subnormal), which `%f` reports as 0.00000. The non-zero part is actually the low end of the significand, with an exponent of 0. On a big-endian architecture, you'd get 9.44473296573929e+21 thanks to the non-zero exponent.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thanks for the correction. Do you get how 1.401...e-43 comes from? I can get this number from "%g", but the minimal float should be only 1.175494351e-38F.